# What are the most recent instructions on setting up a Windows 8 Monogame Project?

Tags: windows-8, xna, visual-studio-2012, monogame

I'm having trouble following all of the "tutorials" and "documentation" MonoGame is providing for building a Windows 8 App. The setup is outdated because the directories don't match anymore. I installed MonoGame with the latest binary and I can access the Windows 8 template in VS 2012. I can actually use images fine and compile and do a great amount of work done, but the audio and spritefonts don't work after I've followed the importing of the xnb files from VS2010 as documented. Also, are there any Windows8 Monogame samples? I could not find one.

Answer (score 2):

You might give this post by Bob Familiar a try:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/02/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-2-getting-started.aspx

Just take note of some of the post's comments by Dave Voyles noting some name changes since the original post.

As for MonoGame samples for Windows 8, the [third post in the series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/07/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-3-code-migration-and-windows-8-feature-support.aspx) happens to have a walkthrough for creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Answer (score 0):

The MonoGame 3.0 Stable Released on Mon, Jan 21st which include a Windows installer that will install all the MonoGame templates for Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 without have to bring down the MonoGame 3.0 Branch from GitHub.   Installer can be found here: http://monogame.codeplex.com/downloads/get/601094

If you need step by step instructions look at my post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx

This is a step by step tutorial to build a Windows 8 XNA MonoGame, which also covers .xnb files.  If you need Content Processors for Cross Platform support of different textures, font, sound, etc. Look at the MonoGame wiki about Content Processing/Processors on their monogame.net site. Sorry I can't provide the link to the Content Processor info, StackOverflow won't let me post more than 2 links as a new user.